# How to load assets via JSONP into Phaser

Tags: javascript, jsonp, phaser-framework

I am trying to load data (including images) via a JSONP feed into Phaser 3.60.0. I know how to load image asset normally as per my GameScene.js code below:

```
class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'GameScene' });
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image('oranges', './assets/Ambersweet_oranges.jpg');
  }

  create() {
    this.add.image(240, 320, 'oranges')
  }
}
```

The JSONP feed is located on a different server and is structured like this:

```
/**/ typeof handleItems === 'function' && handleItems([
{"offerWeek":"kw17","id":"1028377","name":"Bananen","price":"1.79","url":"https://www.rewe.de/angebote/nationale-angebote/#1028377","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Pl%C3%A1tanos_de_Canarias.JPG"},
{"offerWeek":"kw17","id":"2670547","name":"Big City Pizza","price":"1.99","url":"https://www.rewe.de/angebote/nationale-angebote/#2670547","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Pizza_20.jpg"},
{"offerWeek":"kw17","id":"3663221","name":"Die Thüringer Bratwurst","price":"4.59","url":"https://www.rewe.de/angebote/nationale-angebote/#3663221","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Bratwurst_on_the_grill.jpg"},
{"offerWeek":"kw17","id":"3919250","name":"Orangen","price":"2.99","url":"https://www.rewe.de/angebote/nationale-angebote/#3919250","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Ambersweet_oranges.jpg"}]
);
```

How do I access the product names and images and display them in Phaser? Also how do I wait for the request to finish before create() is called? All advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better solution, but my first idea would be:

1. create a global variabel, like this

   ```
    var globalItemsStore = { isLoaded: false, inGame: false,  items: []};
   ```
2. create the jsonp callback function, like this

   ```
    function handleItems(loadedItems){
        globalItemsStore = {
            isLoaded: true,
            inGame: false, 
            items: loadedItems
        };
    }
   ```
3. Now in your game in the `update` method of the scene, you can check for the finished load, like this
   *(Or alternative just use the global variable)*

   ```
    ...
    update(){
        ...
        if(!globalItemsStore.inGame && globalItemsStore.isLoaded){
            // Do your thing ...
            globalItemsStore.inGame = true;
        }
    }
    ...
   ```

**OR** if you want to use events and emitters in phaser, here is a small example:

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:10px;';

var button = document.querySelector('#button');
const DEMO_ITEMS = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

button.addEventListener('click', () => handleItems(DEMO_ITEMS));

function handleItems (items){
    game.scene.scenes[0].events.emit('DATA-LOADED', items);
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 143,
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click the HTML Button to simulate,\nloading Data.')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    // you can use any string for the event Name
    this.events.on('DATA-LOADED', args => {
      console.info(args);
      this.add.text(10, 80, `Data loaded!\nItemCount: ${args.length}`)
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial', color: 'green'});
    });
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<button id="button" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> Simulate Load Data </button> <br>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

*Just:*

1. create an event listener in the `create` method, with `this.events.on(...);` *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Events.EventEmitter.html#on__anchor))*
2. In the **jsonp** callback function, call the `scene.events.emit(...)` function. *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Events.EventEmitter.html#emit__anchor))*

> *You just have to select the correct scene. If you only have one it is easy*

**If you only want to start the game after loading the data**, the easy solution would be to create the game in the `handleItems` function. Something like this

```
    function handleItems(loadedItems){
       var game = new Phaser.Game(config)
       game._myLoadedItems = loadedItems;
    }
```

and in the create function you could get the data like this:

```
   create(){
       console.info(this.game._myLoadedItems);
       ...
   }
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much for your comprehensive and accurate answer. I am using the Phaser events and emitters as per your example :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'm glad I could help. If it solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer with the green checkmark. Thanks in advance.